How do I create a graph of the average value of an log attribute using Datadog?
My mobile app is posting the following log messages to Datadog:
logger.log(
    priority = Log.INFO,
    message = "Jank Report",
    attributes = mapOf(
        "percent_jank" to percentJank, // floating-point number
        "duration_ms" to durationMs    // integer in ms
    )
)

I can see the log entries in Log Explorer. I want to create graphs on my dashboard that display the average percent_jank and duration_ms. I'd also like to create distribution graphs of those values but I have no idea how to reference them on my dashboard.
Can someone please explain or point me at the right docs, or at least tell me if it's even possible?
